# Hide/rename a word in URL

Tags: wordpress, url, url-rewriting

This is the url of my page http://cbiance.com/wordpress/. Is there a way to hide 'wordpress' in the url or change it to something? 
Thanks

Comment: You need to change the folder name WP is installed in to something else (Via FTP) then change all references to the old URL in the data base with [this](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

Answer (score 0):

The `"/wordpress/"` is the dir of the page. You can either

1. Rename the dir and change all the referring documents fo correct it (This includes any other page that links to it and Configuration files like your `apache.conf` for example.
2. You could also move the page to the location of url that you would like and  redirect from the current page, allowing old links to remain valid.
3. Use configuration of your `apache.conf` (or whatever your using) to chang your root dir to this location turning the current URL into "

> http://cbiance.com/

The third is the preffered method.